Issue with Redirecting to Login Page After Successful Login in Nuxt.js from Laravel Api
I'm working on a project in Nuxt.js adn Laravel api and I've encountered an issue with redirecting users after a successful login. After logging in, the user is redirected immediately to the dashboard (/dashboard), which works as expected. However, if the user then manually enters the home page URL (http://localhost:3000), they are briefly redirected to the login page (/) for about a second before the middleware fetches the user data and redirects them back to the dashboard. This flicker looks very unprofessional and confusing for users.
Middleware Code
Here's a simplified version of my authentication middleware:
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    const { me, user } = useAuth();

    try {
        await me(); 
        if (!user.value) {
            return navigateTo('/'); 
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error loading user data:", error);
        return navigateTo('/'); 
    }
});


And my guest middleware:
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    const { me, user } = useAuth();

    if (!user.value) {
        try {
            await me(); 
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error loading user data:", error);
        }
    }

    if (user.value) {
        return navigateTo('/dashboard'); 
    }
});


This is my useAuth.js
export default function useAuth() {
    const user = useState('auth-user', () => null)

    const { errorBag, transformValidationErrors, resetErrorBag } = useCustomError()

    const { api, csrf } = useAxios()

    async function me() {
        try {
            const data = await api.get("/api/me")
            user.value = data.data
        } catch (e) {
            user.value = null
            console.log("error")
        }
    }

    function login(userForm) {
        resetErrorBag();
        csrf().then(() => {
            api.post("/login", userForm)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                user.value = data.user;
    
                $fetch('/api/set-cookie', {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: { token: data.token }
                }).then(res => {
                    navigateTo("/dashboard");
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                // Don't set the user or token on error
                user.value = null;
                transformValidationErrors(err.response);
            });
        });
    }


    function logout() {
        api.post("/api/logout").then(() => {
            user.value = null
            $fetch('/api/logout', {
                method: "POST",
            }).then(res => {
                navigateTo("/")
            })

        })
    }

    function register(userForm) {

        resetErrorBag()
        csrf().then(() => {
            api.post("/register", userForm).then(({ data }) => {
                //   verify email screen
            }).catch(err => {
                transformValidationErrors(err.response)
            })
        })
    }

    function forgotPassword(userForm){
        resetErrorBag()
        
        csrf().then(() => {

            api.post('/forgot-password', userForm).then(({data}) => {
                alert("Odkaz na obnovení hesla byl úspěšně odeslán na váš email.");
            }).catch(err => {
                transformValidationErrors(err.response)
            })
        })

    }

    function resetPassword(userForm){
        resetErrorBag()
            api.post('/reset-password', userForm).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                navigateTo("/")
            }).catch(err => {
                transformValidationErrors(err.response)
            })
    }

    return { login, logout, register, errorBag, user, me, forgotPassword, resetPassword }

}

In some way, I simply need to maintain the authenticated user state throughout the entire process, but I am struggling to achieve that
